# Cannot send DIO post request with multiple form-data body json and image with Flutter

Tags: flutter, request, form-data, dio

I am currently try to send a post request that works in Postman :

```
curl --location --request POST 'https://demo-recofaciale.openground.fr/visitors/' \
--form 'visitor="{\"uuid\": \"611633d2766081d524d5fbc3\", \"locale\": \"fr\", \"name\": \"Xxxx XXXXXXX\", \"photoUrl\": \"\"}";type=application/json' \
--form 'photoFile=@"/C:/Users/xxxxxx/Pictures/my-photo.jpeg"'
```

with Flutter (Flutter 2.2.3) and his Dio (dio: ^4.0.0) package, but I did'nt succeed.

Here is what I tried:

```
      var dio = dio_package.Dio();
      
      File imageFile = File(photo.path!);
      String? id = client == null ? _session.user!.id : client.id;
      String name = client == null
          ? "${_session.user!.firstName} ${_session.user!.lastName}"
          : "${client.firstName} ${client.lastName}";

      var file = await dio_package.MultipartFile.fromFile(imageFile.path,
          filename: basename(imageFile.path),
          contentType: MediaType("image", basename(imageFile.path)));

      var formData = dio_package.FormData.fromMap({
        "visitor": json
            .encode({"uuid": id, "locale": "fr", "name": name, "photoUrl": ""})
      });

      formData.files.add(MapEntry('photoFile', file));
      
      dio.options.baseUrl = _config.url!;
      await dio.post(
        "/visitors",
        data: formData,
      );
```

this code returned error Content type 'application/octet-stream' not supported | Status: 415

If anyone has already get thies errors, thanks for advance for your help